# Bash. getopts command. option that will do something at the end of the program

Tags: bash, getopts

Problem:
If my program takes option '-v' it should print "Good bye!" at the end of the program. I can do this, but it will print it at the beginning. So I need some command that will execute it in the end, if any. Or how can I do this?

```
 getopts "v" opt
 case ${opt} in
 v) echo "Good bye!"
 esac
```

Comment: what is a "smth"?

Comment: @poixen: Probably an abbreviation for "something". I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just set a variable while parsing the options, and at the end of the script, based on the value of the variable you'll perform your desired action

```
say_bye=false
while getopts "v" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    v) say_bye=true ;;
  esac
done

# do stuff

# and at the end:
$say_bye && echo "Good bye!"
```

If your script has multiple potential end points, and you want to say bye for all of them, use an EXIT trap

```
say_bye=false
while getopts "v" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    v) say_bye=true ;;
  esac
done

end_business() {
    $say_bye && echo byebye
}
trap end_business EXIT

# do the rest of your script here ...
```

Comment: This looks **really dangerous**! Randomly executing the contents of a variable, just to test if the variable is set.

Comment: @randomir: There's nothing random about it it you control the value of the variable yourself. If its only possible values are `false` and `true`, executing it is safe.

Comment: It's utterly fragile and non-intuitive for someone reading the code later. Why not `say_bye=0`/`say_bye=1` and then `(( say_bye )) && action`?

Comment: Or `[[ -n $say_bye ]] && echo byebye`, and set `say_bye` to any non_empty string above.

Comment: @randomir, I don't understand your concern. `true` and `false` are not even external commands: they are bash builtins. To be most understood, I could write `if [[ $say_bye = "true" ]]; then ...; fi` -- I find both of your suggestions equally terse to mine.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but why would you want to *evaluate the contents of your variable as a shell command*, just to test the actual value of the variable? `[[ $say_bye = "true" ]]` is perfect, I suggested `((say_bye))` in case you wanted terseness.

Comment: I think it's elegant. You would do the same in other languages when a variable holds a boolean value. The opposite question applies to you too: why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `-v` is intended as "verbose", I like to `set -x` in many scripts to get debugging output. If you do that, you can pepper your script with no-op statements like this, which act as comments for the reader when not verbose, but output to stderr when verbose is on -

```
: setting x to "$x"
```

This dovetails nicely with a trap on EXIT, as mentioned by @[glenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) already. Thus,

```
while getopts "v" opt
do case "$opt" in
   v) verbose=1 # in case you need other contingent code bits
      set -v ;;
   esac
done
```

Then

```
trap ' : "bye-bye!" ' EXIT
```

That will execute harmlessly and output nothing if `set -x` is off.